Extracting Email Attachments Using Power Automate Cloud Flows
I'm trying to find a way to open email attachments of the type "Outlook item" in Power Automate. At the moment, I have tried using the "Get attachment" action and "Get email" action to try to extract the mentioned attachment but none of these has quite worked out. Both actions are accustomed to traditional PDF, JPG, and other attachments.
With the "Get attachment" action, the main challenge stems from the inability of flows to identify the 'Attachment Id' of the Outlook item thus making it impossible to save or run the flow.
Is there perhaps a way to work around this, or maybe a more suitable connector for extracting Outlook item attachments?

you can definitely use the get email and get attachments actions to extract attachments from emails. What exactly have you tried that did not work?

For the two fields required in Get Attachment, I used the dynamic contents of 'Message Id' and 'Attachments Attachment Id'. The flow works with regular attachments but not for emails that are sent as attachments within another email.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

What exactly is the problem? Not being able to save or run the flow is a different problem than not being able to identify the attachment.
